# What does 'vector-like' mean?

Tags: terminology, vectors, field-theory

What are properties of vector-like field/particle? What's the counterpart of it? Chiral like?

Comment: Is there any more context as to where you saw this said?

Comment: @tmwilson26 In the context of particle physics and qft. I think it should be enough, right?