# Why do we use "vector-like" to mean "non-chiral", in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, beyond-the-standard-model, chirality

I've been reading some stuff about searches for [vector-like quarks](https://sites.physics.utoronto.ca/pekkasinervo/vector-like-quark-searches-at-atlas) and [vector-like leptons](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269320305554), and I'm a little confused about the terminology.

Also, I'm a little new to this, so bear with me.

As far as I can tell, these particles' wave functions are superpositions of right- and left-helicity wavefunctions, where left- or right-helicity is whether the particle's spin is aligned or anti-aligned with its momentum.

And chirality is whether or not the left- and right-helicity components transform identically under gauge transformations or not.

As far as I can tell, vector-like means non-chiral (i.e. the two components do transform identically, which is not the same as for standard model particles which don't transform identically).

**What I'm confused about is the use of the word "vector-like" for this... How is this like a vector?**

Let me know if I've misunderstood something above too!

Also, basically the same question exists on stackexchange [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219673/what-does-vector-like-mean) (from 6 years ago), but the asker didn't provide any background to help their question get answered, so I figured it was worth asking again in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the left and right components belong to the same representation of the gauge group, then the gauge field couples to the *vector current*,
\begin{equation}
j_\mu^{(V)}=\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi=\bar{\psi}_L\gamma^\mu\psi_L+\bar{\psi}_R\gamma^\mu\psi_R
\end{equation}
We can also introduce the *axial current*,
\begin{equation}
j_\mu^{(A)}=\bar{\psi}\gamma_5\gamma^\mu\psi=\bar{\psi}_R\gamma^\mu\psi_R-\bar{\psi}_L\gamma^\mu\psi_L
\end{equation}
For the known leptons and quarks the weak interaction couples to the $V-A$ current,
\begin{equation}
j_\mu^{(V)}-j_\mu^{(A)}=2\bar{\psi}_L\gamma^\mu\psi_L
\end{equation}
The name *vector-like* implies that for those particles the weak interaction couples to the vector current.